# Directory: Is a directory

Tags: python, linux, cron, cron-task

I've set up a cron job to run a Python script to scrape some web pages.

**/etc/crontab**

```
    GNU nano 2.3.1                                  File: crontab

    SHELL=/bin/bash
    PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    MAILTO=my_email_address@domain.com

    # For details see man 4 crontabs

    # Example of job definition:
    # .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
    # |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
    # |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
    # |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
    # |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
    # |  |  |  |  |
    # *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed

    */2 * * * * root /usr/bin scrapy crawl mycrawler
```

However, the emails are informing me that...

`/bin/bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory`

When I manually run the script, it pipes data into my database, but when the cron job executes the script, nothing...

**What does the `/bin/bash: /usr/bin: Is a directory` message allude to?!**

Comment: `*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin scrapy crawl mycrawler` should be ` */2 * * * * root /usr/bin/python scrapy crawl mycrawler` ... or just `  */2 * * * * root scrapy crawl mycrawler`

Comment: @MatthewStory when i run `*/2 * * * * root scrapy crawl mycrawler`, i start getting emails that say `/bin/bash: scrapy: command not found`

Comment: what is the output of `which scrapy` from your shell?

Comment: @MatthewStory `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`. however, python is located at `/usr/bin/python` which is also a dependency of the script

Comment: Posted answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments the very initial error is that the entry places `/usr/bin` where the executable should be:

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin scrapy crawl mycrawler
                 ^^^^^^^^
                 command
```

Once fixed to be `scapy`, the ultimate issue is that `scrapy` is in `/usr/local/bin` which is not in your `PATH`. To change this:

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/
```

And then you should be able to just do:

```
 */2 * * * * root cd <project dir> && scrapy crawl mycrawler
```

Comment: won't that overwrite `PATH` altogether? i have other things in path that you haven't listed. wouldn't `PATH=$PATH:...` be a lot more appropriate

Comment: PATH in your crontab is always just what it is ... cron unsets all environment variables before running. In this case I merely appended /usr/local/bin to the path definition already defined in the crontab you posted in your OP.

Comment: so it's basically an "isolated" version of `PATH`? that won't effect everything else that i've stored in `PATH`?

Comment: yeah, it's just the path used in cron ... and as I said ... you've already set it in your crontab, we're just adding `/usr/local/bin` to it. you could prepend `$PATH` to that if it makes you feel better, but it won't do anything as cron unsets env.

Comment: now i'm getting the error `Scrapy 1.5.0 - no active project -- Unknown command: crawl -- Use "scrapy" to see available commands`. that shouldn't be the case.

Comment: You likely need to `cd` into a project directory, as discussed in chat.

Comment: yes, trust me, it's working fine outside of the cron job. it's just this cron job bs :/

Comment: use the absolute path of the crawl and mycrawler files in the command

Comment: Yeah ... it's also worth noting that `PYTHONPATH` is not set in cron ... so if you need it set you have to do so explicitly in your crontab

Comment: @jesse crawl isn't a file, but i'll try using the absolute path for mycrawler. `cd` to the path apparently made the emails stop working and the script still isnt working :/

Comment: did you use the `&&` between the cd and the scrapy?

Comment: so basically i need to add all of the paths of any dependency?

Comment: yeah for PATH and PYTHONPATH ... as well as any other environment information you might typically assume (e.g. stuff loaded by your bashrc) as cron not only doesn't load your rc file, it also unsets all environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin
```

Is a fairly standard directory on Unix-like operating systems that contains most of the executable files.

i.e. you are trying to have cron execute the "scrapy crawl mycrawler" with an executable that is a directory.

You would generally have to execute a bash script (assuming bash binary is in /usr/bin directory):

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/bash scrapy.sh
```

Or a python command (again assuming python binary is in /usr/bin directory)

```
*/2 * * * * root /usr/bin/python scrapy.py
```

OR you could add scrapy absolute path to your PATH variable:

```
*/2 * * * * root scrapy crawl mycrawler
```

Comment: it's funny because on my other question i was just informed that my code would be fine :/ that i could do this without creating and referencing a shell script

Comment: surely it's possible without creating and referencing a shell script... i mean, `scrapy crawl mycrawler` is a shell command...

Comment: You can do it without creating a shell script. Python binary needs to be either referenced i.e. /usr/bin/python script.py (where script.py is a python script), or python needs to be part of the path. The path is where your system will look for binaries consecutively to execute a command.

Comment: i believe i need to execute the script by issuing the command `scrapy crawl mycrawler`

Comment: Okay you need to add scrapy to your PATH variable then. I assume scrapy is binary?

Comment: ill try that. scrapy is also dependent on python so?

Comment: AS long as python is also in your PATH, you shouldn't have any trouble.

Comment: still getting errors with the absolute path... :/ `Scrapy 1.5.0 - no active project

Unknown command: crawl

Use "scrapy" to see available commands`